# Keep session on server side app after ajax request - cross domain

Tags: php, ajax, cordova, session, cross-domain

I have a server side web application built in `PHP` using `Slim Framework`. This application is just providing web services to another on the cross domain. I am creating login using `AJAX` request.

The `client-side` application which is another domain has built in `ReactJS` actually I am building `Phonegap` Application. I send the login request from my `client-side` application to check and match the credentials using `AJAX`, If matched its return user data in `JSON` Array. This is how I am working, now:

**Problem:** On success login I am also trying to store or create session in my `server-side` application to authenticate some other request if the user is logged in. I am also storing the cookies, but also want to store session for some secure data storage. But the session doesn't store or create on `AJAX` Request.

How I can create or store session on AJAX Request from cross domain?

My Code is below:

**Server Side:**

```
$app->get('/login/{username}/{password}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {

    $username = $request->getAttribute('username');
    $password = $request->getAttribute('password');

    $user = $this->eloquent->table('u')
                        ->select('*')
                            ->where('username', $username)
                            ->where('password', $password)->get();
    $_SESSION['user_auth'] = 1;
    $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($user));

    return $response;
});
```

**Client Side:**

```
$.ajax({
            url : config.remoteAddr + '/login/' + username + '/' + password,
            type : 'get',
            dataType : 'json',
            async : false,
        }).done(function(data){
            if(data[0]){
                alert('loggedin');
                console.log(data);
                cookie.set('auth', '1', {path : '/'});
                cookie.set('userId', data[0].id , {path : '/'});
                error = false;
            }
        }).fail(function(){
            console.log('fail');
        })
```